# How to pull private images from GCR in drone?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, drone.io, google-container-registry

I have been looking in how to pull private images and I found [this](http://docs.drone.io/manage-registry-credentials/#configuration).

I'm trying to use the drone cli to it but when i use this command

```
drone registry add \
  --repository octocat/hello-world \
  --hostname gcr.io \
  --username _json_key \
  --password @/absolute/path/to/keyfile.json
```

It returns me a error:
`Client error: 404`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a custom registry, the repo needs to exist at the time of running `drone registry add`.

You can run `drone repo ls` (show all repos) or `drone repo info octocat/hello-world` to confirm your repo exists.

Comment: I already fixed it. I was misspelling the repository name. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I little late here, but for me, this worked (and my help others coming in the future):

```
drone exec --trusted --secret-file=secrets.txt --event=push .drone.yaml
```

With the --trusted I was able to download private images, that required authentication, that is passed (in my case was Google Images) using the secrets.txt file.

In drone.yaml:

```
    pull: if-not-exists
    image: eu.gcr.io/private-org/private-repo/latest
    environment:
        GITHUB_TOKEN:
            from_secret: GITHUB_TOKEN
```

The secrets.txt file contains just (a valid) GitHub token:

```
GITHUB_TOKEN=ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```